# Google Sheets get QUERY clause from IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, filter, import, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a QUERY in Google Sheets, like:

`=QUERY('Sheet1'!A:C, "select A where C <100")`

That works perfect, BUT... what if I want to get this "100" value, from another document? Like:

`=QUERY('Sheet1'!A:C, "select A where C < IMPORTRANGE("GoogleSheetURL", "Sheet!$A$1")")`

I've tried with many syntax and ways to include this IMPORTRANGE in the clause, without success! =(
It´s impossible??... or It´s just I'm doing it not as it is supossed to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A:C; 
 "select A 
  where C < "&IMPORTRANGE("GoogleSheetURL"; "Sheet!A1"))
```

Comment: it returns an #ERROR! in the formula...
(I've even tryed this before)  =(

Comment: @LeoMilani The given formula should work. Please remember to **first connect the 2 sheets** (by using `IMPORTRANGE("GoogleSheetURL", "Sheet!$A$1")` by itself outside the formula) and THEN use it in the formula.

Comment: @marikamitsos so... I think maybe it´s just a SYNTAX matter... since I'm using spanish version of google sheets?? I can´t believe that could be!   =(

Comment: @LeoMilani *"I'm using spanish version"* Then you just need to change `,` to `;`

Comment: @marikamitsos yes, of course I know this is a main difference and I'm aware of it.- Anyway... there should be another syntax difference?? (like when making an array, that requires totally different characters to denote columns and rows?)... I'm going crazy, knowing it should work and I'm stucked by a syntax mistake!

Comment: @LeoMilani If still having issues please share a test sheet.

Comment: @marikamitsos I made a sample to share... and even, tryed to do it here, and I couldn't get it either  =(

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yrY2jOeOPR-C8FeMZODY4NGM8dJhsMTpGJ1-gG6dqe4/edit#gid=0

Comment: @LeoMilani Try `=QUERY(B:C;"select B where C >"&IMPORTRANGE("1wgFI09VXaG1UX5PJn6LU7glx_VE4jcmw2d3gVpjH53M";"Hoja 1!$A$1"))`

Comment: @marikamitsos You are definitely the best!! I couldn't have solved it without your help. Many MANY thanks!  =)

Comment: You had miswritten  the formula given by player0

Comment: @marikamitsos SORRY... I see it´s working OK at the sample sheet, but I'm not able to see the difference on what player0 proposed at first and I tried before with no success! - Could you tell me WHAT have you fixed in the formula, to get it work?? Because when I transfer it to the real spreadsheet (with real URLs and sheet data), I can´t get it to work either! jejeje

Comment: @marikamitsos Yep, I noted it. So I corrected it in the sheet and the formula worked like a charm. Even that, I colud not get it work in the real document.
Here is too late and may be it´s my brain! jejeje
I will check it tomorrow... my be a typo... my fault. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!  =)

Comment: Most likely a typo. Have a good rest. Tomorrow is another day :)